Animated series (or movie/tv show) of a daughter carrying a flower pot
I saw some screens of a movie/TV show/animated series recently (can't remember exactly which, but I think it was an animated series).
The only thing I remember (kind of) well is the cover. It depicted a rather wasted-looking daughter carrying a flower pot in one hand, and a cigar in the other. I think she was wearing a white/pink shirt and a short skirt. Her father (or uncle) was near the bottom of the cover, with glasses and a checked shirt. It was cartoonish.
Overall it had a pretty dark and depressing feel about it. But I also heard that this is a pretty well-known series (or movie).
Any help in identifying this is appreciated!

There is a high possibility it could be Leon: The professional (1994). I have already asked a question about it here. It has many cartoon posters like this one: 

The movie is not a cartoon, check all the covers here.

Yes, that's it! :D Thanks! Sorry, I did do a search before asking the question, wasn't able to find yours...

You welcome. Amazing movie indeed. Thanks @Walt for identifying it in the first place ;)
